# Why would the size of /proc/stat show as zero?

Tags: linux, filesystems, proc, size

```
ls -rlth /proc/stat
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 21 04:25 /proc/stat
```

Although if we `cat` it, its got enough contents.

Comment: Please read this web page -> http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

proc is a virtual file system mapping file names to internal linux structures/variables; so it is normal /proc/stat having 0 bytes.

From wikipedia: [procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)

> The proc filesystem (procfs) is a special filesystem in Unix-like
>   operating systems that presents information about processes and other
>   system information in a hierarchical file-like structure, providing a
>   more convenient and standardized method for dynamically accessing
>   process data held in the kernel than traditional tracing methods or
>   direct access to kernel memory. Typically, it is mapped to a mount
>   point named /proc at boot time. The proc file system acts as an
>   interface to internal data structures in the kernel. It can be used to
>   obtain information about the system and to change certain kernel
>   parameters at runtime (sysctl).

From TLDP [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy: /proc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html)

> The most distinctive thing about files in this directory is the fact
>   that all of them have a file size of 0, with the exception of kcore,
>   mtrr and self.

Note: Actually only mtrr and self are 0 size in my servers - kcore is the memory that you are able to address, i.e. kernel virtual memory addresses hence the 128TB. Also relevant for this discussion, is `/proc/kcore` not  being implemented in MIPS and ARM architectures.

Answer (score 5):

That's because it is a virtual file that has no predefined known size, the actual size, i.e. the amount of data returned will vary depending on when you read it.

Some `/proc` files might have a non null size because it is known in advance.

```
   /proc/kcore
          This  file  represents the physical memory of the system and is stored in the ELF core file for-
          mat.  With this pseudo-file, and an unstripped kernel (/usr/src/linux/vmlinux) binary,  GDB  can
          be used to examine the current state of any kernel data structures.

          The total length of the file is the size of physical memory (RAM) plus 4KB.
```

However, given the fact I haven't 128 TB of RAM on my machine, the reported value and the size that might be read do not match the documentation:

```
$ ls -lh /proc/kcore
-r--------. 1 root root 128T Feb 23 16:10 /proc/kcore
```

Comment: And some have a non-null size that doesn't correspond to the number of bytes that you can read from them (like `/proc/bus/pci/*/*`). There are a lot more of those in `/sys`.

Comment: kcore is the memory that you are able to address, i.e. kernel virtual memory addresses hence the 128TB

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I do not question that, just the documentation that wrongly states the displayed size should be "size of RAM + 4KB"

Comment: @jlliagre and in one of my old 32 bits-server with 521MB, kcore has 1GB.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That's what I suspected, the documentation lags or doesn't match the implementation. A common issue with Linux.

Answer (score 4):

`/proc` is a special file system. It is not something that you store files in. It is a virtual filesystem, I know it is not the right analogy but consider it something like device driver in your `/dev` directory. What you write to the files in `/dev` gets passed on to the system in some way. Likewise, when you read from a file, it pulls those values from the system. Hence, since there is no actual stored information in these files, the size shows as zero.