# Byte count of "ls -l <random file>" versus that of "wc -c <random file>"

Tags: ls, wc, byte

Is there any possible situation when

```
ls -l file.txt
```

is showing not the same number of bytes as

```
wc -c file.txt
```

In one script I found comparison of those two values. What could be the reason of that? Is it even possible to have different byte counts of the same file?

Comment: Could you give some context to this script that you found?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321502/22565

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there are such cases.

In case of **symlinks** on Linux system with GNU `ls`, the `ls -l` will put out the size of the link, while `wc -c` will resolve the actual file and read number of bytes there. Below you can see that `ls -l` reports 29 bytes , while `wc` reports 172 bytes in the actual file.

```
$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf                                                                                                 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 1月  17  2016 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
$ wc -c /etc/resolv.conf                                                                                                 
172 /etc/resolv.conf
$ wc -c /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf                                                                                  
172 /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
$ ls -l /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf                                                                                  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 172 1月  15 15:49 /var/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

In case of **virtual filesystems**, [such as `/proc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265233/85039)  or `/sys` , many files there will show  as having size 0 `ls -l`.  Under `/dev` filesystem we have variety of special files, such as character devices and block devices - `wc -c` hangs on those and `ls -l` shows [major and minor numbers](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition-Mass-Storage-Definitions-Naming-HOWTO/x183.html) instead of size.

**Named pipes** will be reported as `0` bytes by `ls -c`, but `wc -c` will actually read the contents of the pipe, so technically it will tell you how much data is in the named pipe:

```
$ mkfifo named.pipe                                                                                                      
$ echo "This is a test" > named.pipe &
[1] 2129
$ ls -l named.pipe
prw-rw-r-- 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 1月  16 08:40 named.pipe|
$ wc -c named.pipe
15 named.pipe
[1] + Done                 echo "This is a test" >named.pipe
```

For a regular files, the size should be equal.

---

The point of `ls -l` and `wc -c`, and how they work also differs. `wc -c` actually opens file for reading ( you can see that if you run `strace wc -c /etc/passwd` for example). `ls -l` only performs `stat()` call on those. This also explains why in `/proc` `ls -l` shows 0 size - you can't stat those files because they aren't "real" or actually stored on the hard-drive/ssd. `wc -c` instead, reads the *contents* of that file, and calculates its size.

Finally, `ls -l` is only a tool for listing items interactively. It's rarely a good fit for scripting. When you actually need to read the data, use `wc -c` instead.

Please note, that for scripting and assessing size of a file, `ls` is not the best candidate. In fact , it is a one of the common practices to [avoid parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Please use `du -b`  for finding out the size of a file.

Comment: A small clarification - virtual files (in `/sys/`, `/proc/`, etc) *may* provide `stat` information, if the implementer chooses to.  Most of the time, there isn't a compelling reason to, so it's omitted.  Examples include `/proc/kcore` which is reported as the size of addressable kernel memory (usually much more than the available physical memory).

Answer (score 12):

`ls -l` will return the size of the file reported by the filesystem.

`wc -c` will attempt to read the file to determine the 'actual' size. From my observations it appears to first try seeking to the end, and if this doesn't work, it will read out the entire file, counting the size as it goes.

This is a simple description as to what the two tools do, but it leads to a number of implications for the results:

`ls` will give an incorrect output for certain filesystems. For example, virtualised filesystems like `/proc` will report a size of zero for many files, because these "files" aren't physically stored anywhere; they are generated as required by software.

`wc` will not function at all for files without read permissions, whereas `ls` requires only permissions to list the directory (compare `ls -l /etc/shadow` to `wc -c /etc/shadow`).

As mentioned in other answers, the behaviour for symbolic links is also different. Because `wc` tries to read them, it ends up reading the file to which the symlink points, whereas because `ls` just queries the filesystem, it will report the size used to store the symbolic link itself.

I'm sure there are other differences that I haven't thought of yet, but I thought I'd give a clear and simple explanation as to the basic reason behind these differences.

Comment: +1 for mentioning read permissions and `seek()`. This appears to be the case , after running `strace wc -l` on a couple large files.

Comment: +1 for adding much more detail than my answer!

Answer (score 6):

For a normal file, ls and wc call stat. However, for a file of /proc or /sys, ls returns 0, but wc returns a different number:

```
$ ls -l /proc/modules
-r--r--r--  1 root root 0 Jan 16 14:56 modules
                        ^ this one
$ wc -c /proc/modules
7621 modules
```

This is probably some way of finding out if something is a special file.

Comment: `wc -c` for me at least does call `fstat`, but seemingly for other purposes. It finds the length of the file by `lseek`ing to the end. In the event that this returns an error, it `read`s the whole file.